# Test if a variable is serializable

Tags: php, serialization, closures

I'm looking for an elegant way of testing if a variable is serializable. For example `array( function() {} )` will fail to serialize.

I'm currently using the code below, but it seems to be a rather non-optimal way of doing it.

```
function isSerializable( $var )
{
    try {
        serialize( $var );
        return TRUE;
    } catch( Exception $e ) {
        return FALSE;
    }
}

var_dump( isSerializable( array() ) );                // bool(true)
var_dump( isSerializable( function() {} ) );          // bool(false)
var_dump( isSerializable( array( function() {} ) ) ); // bool(false)
```

Comment: That is a pretty good way of doing it :)

Comment: Yeah I agree with alex, this looks totally fine. Are you concerned with the overhead attempting to serialize?

Comment: i think that is best way, and other way not exist :)

Comment: Well I'm trying to write a function that will allow serialization of normal serializable variables + Closures (using [this](https://github.com/jeremeamia/super_closure/blob/master/SerializableClosure.php)). So I'm attempting to traverse the object tree looking for Closure that could exist (and preventing the serialization) by using a function `isSerializable` to "traverse" the variable. This could be very slow if I have to try to do a deep serialize at each point.

Comment: Why not have the function return the serialized object or false? Then you've got your data serialized already. Sry didn't read the code you linked to.

Comment: In php version PHP 5.6.25, serializing a resource type does not result in an Exception.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The alternative could be:

```
function isSerializable ($value) {
  $return = true;
  $arr = array($value);

  array_walk_recursive($arr, function ($element) use (&$return) {
    if (is_object($element) && get_class($element) == 'Closure') {
      $return = false;
    }
  });

  return $return;
}
```

But from comments I think this is what you are looking for:

```
function mySerialize ($value) {
  $arr = array($value);

  array_walk_recursive($arr, function (&$element) {

    # do some special stuff (serialize closure) ...
    if (is_object($element) && get_class($element) == 'Closure') {
      $serializableClosure = new SerializableClosure($element);
      $element = $serializableClosure->serialize();
    }

  });

  return serialize($arr[0]);
}
```

Comment: This misses a check for it being a resource.

Comment: Or any other object that isn't serializable.

Answer (score 1):

Late answer but...

[**According to PHP documentation**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php), vars of the Resource type cannot be serialized.
However, at least in PHP 5.4, trying to serialize a Resource will not trigger any error.

I think a better approach would be to test for closures and resources without try/catch:

```
$resource = fopen('composer.json', 'r');
$closure = function() {
    return 'bla';
};
$string = 'string';

function isSerializable($var)
{
    if (is_resource($var)) {
        return false;
    } else if ($var instanceof Closure) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

var_dump(isSerializable($resource));
var_dump(isSerializable($closure));
var_dump(isSerializable($string));
```

Outputs:

```
boolean false 
boolean false
boolean true
```

Comment: No idea why someone -1 this... but anyway.

You should also check if it is an `object`, and if so, if it implements `Serializable`.

Comment: This fails if `$var` is an array that contains non serializable values.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I'm using. It combines a number of suggestions here, plus a check for `instaneof ArrayAccess` which should be serializable.

```
if (!function_exists('is_iterable')) {
    function is_iterable($var) {
        return is_array($var) || (is_object($var) && ($var instanceof \Traversable));
    }
}

function is_serializable($var, $iterate=true) {
    if (is_resource($var)) {
        return false;
    } else if (is_object($var)) {
        if ($var instanceof Closure) {
            return false;
        } else if (!$var instanceof Serializable && !$var instanceof ArrayAccess) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    if ($iterate && is_iterable($var)) {
        foreach ($var as $key => $value) {
            if (!is_serializable($value, true)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```